# Viewport size not working

Tags: css, size, width, viewport

I must be missing something obvious, but here it comes... I just want to establish a narrow viewport width (320px) on my browser to check / design the web layout for a mobile phone display. Why is it that if set a viewport width with the meta tag, the browser doesn't respect it? This is what I do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320px" />
<style>

 .content {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: yellow;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="content">
    <p> Hello, this is the 'content' </p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

It just doesn't matter what size I put in the  tag, it just seems to use the native display size. Can anybody tell me what the problem is and how to actually do it?

Comment: you must use css media query with the viewport tag for the browser to recognize what to do on browser resize. It doesnt initially load the mobile view on browser load. it only responds if the browser is shrinked

Comment: @Godis You should defiantly use media query or browser responsive mode for this. If not then go and learn some coding principles.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set a viewport to check mobile compatibility. Just, click `F + 12` keys in your browser **chrome**, and click on the mobile devices icon. This way you can select any viewport profile and check your design. See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Pablo, I didn't know about this!